# mysql installation stuck on Ubuntu 16.04 (no root user privilege)

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql

In my ubuntu 16.04 server I am trying to install mysql by the following command

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Each time it got stuck with the message :

```
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode 
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present) 
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.16, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to stop it. I have checked the log file in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` and last 10 line of it shows this result:

```
2017-01-18T09:07:30.329930Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170118  9:07:30
2017-01-18T09:07:30.335086Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2017-01-18T09:07:30.335137Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2017-01-18T09:07:30.335157Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2017-01-18T09:07:30.335216Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2017-01-18T09:07:30.349491Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 1 event
2017-01-18T09:07:30.349749Z 0 [Note] Execution of init_file '/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.sJ5rMac6mK' started.
2017-01-18T09:07:30.350543Z 1 [ERROR] 1396  Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'
2017-01-18T09:07:30.350737Z 0 [Note] Execution of init_file '/var/lib/mysql-files/tmp.sJ5rMac6mK' ended.
2017-01-18T09:07:30.350864Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
```

After a reboot I logged in to mysql by `mysql -u root`. within mysql I cannot do any operation, creating new user or modifying privileges nothing. I am just able to browse through default databases

- information_schema
- test

when I typed `show grants` it shows me the following result

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Which is quite strange. To make sure of this I checked the `user_privileges` table in `information_schema` which gives me this:

```
+----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE        | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE | IS_GRANTABLE |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
| ''@'localhost' | def           | USAGE          | NO           |
+----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+
```

How can I enable root access to create, update?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server`?

Comment: @Melebius I have reinstalled several times. still got the error. reinstall also got stuck in the middle with the same error in log file.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

An easy solution is to `sudo killall mysqld` while the apt-get operation is running.

The apt operation just kept on running without any errors after that(!)

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1596815

Comment: this is the best solution! I recommend to do this instead of uninstalling mysql, cause it'll delete all your db!

Comment: Note that you may have to do this more than once during the upgrade process.

Answer (score 12):

At last I got the workaround. Here is what I did

- Uninstall mysql using `sudo apt purge mysql*`
- Remove `/etc/mysql` folder
- Remove `/var/lib/mysql, /var/lib/mysql-files, /var/lib/mysql-kering` folders.
- Reboot
- Install mysql using `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

This time mysql installed successfully without getting stuck. While installation it prompted me for root password and I provided one. After the installation I logged in with root with my provided password. This time creating new user, updating all works fine. Now, here is the result of `show grants`:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Although I still don't know why at first time it didn't work. I tried by removing only the cnf file but that didn't work. When I removed all mysql folders inside `/var/lib` then it worked. So I guess there was some file inside `/var/lib/msyql` directory which prevented to create any new user (even root user).

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for months for a solution to the problems with mysql_server configuration, which froze when installing anything else, thus having to kill the processes and manually start mysql. This also made me have to start MySQL manually each time I restarted the computer.

I edited the /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst and I noticed the configure) part doesn't return anything so it just freezes.

You just need to edit that file and add at the end of the configure) section (before the section on abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-configure) a line that says "exit 0", around line 290. Mine looks now like this:

```
    # To avoid downgrades. This has to happen after the database is created, or --initialize will fail
touch $mysql_statedir/debian-5.7.flag

    exit 0   # Corregimos el bug del postinst de mysql

;;
abort-upgrade|abort-remove|abort-configure)
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3177667 answer is absoulty right one I just make the step with some addition step.

```
1.sudo kill $(pgrep mysql)
2.sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-\*
3.sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
4.Uninstall mysql using sudo apt purge mysql*
5.Remove /etc/mysql folder
6.Remove /var/lib/mysql, /var/lib/mysql-files, /var/lib/mysql-kering folders.
7.Reboot
8.Install mysql using sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because of no root user is created in MySQL. But I don't know why.
Try to insert 'root' user to `mysql.user` table.

Firstly, stop the mysql server.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

To start MySQL with `--skip-grant-tables` option, let try to config `my.cnf`.

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Add following line under `[mysqld]`.

```
 skip-grant-tables
```

Start MySQL server again.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Login to MySQL

```
mysql -u root
```

Insert 'root' user with your desire password.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO mysql.user VALUES ('localhost','root',password('newpassword'),'Y','Y ','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y', 'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','' ,'','','',0,0,0,0); 
mysql> INSERT INTO mysql.user VALUES ('127.0.0.1','root',password('newpassword'),'Y','Y ','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y', 'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','' ,'','','',0,0,0,0);
```

`newpassword` should be change to your desired password.
    mysql> exit

Remove `skip-grant-tables` in `my.cnf` config to use authentication.

After that retart MySQL server in normal way.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Try to login with `root` and your password.

Comment: when I try to login after `--skip-grant-tables` command it gives me this error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: How about with this command `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables --bind-address=127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I had edited the answer with the way of `my.cnf` configuration.

Comment: Thank you @San. I get it to work by just clean sweeping all mysql folders. see my answer.

Comment: Nice answer. Good.