# Cannot reinstall mysql

Tags: server, mysql

I have been having problems with Owncloud after upgrading my server to 18.04 so I decided to try Nextcloud with Mariadb following these [instructions](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-nextcloud-13-on-ubuntu-18-04/) The command "sudo systemctl start mariadb" kept timing out so I gave up and decided to try again with Owncloud and mysql. But then whenever I tried to use "sudo mysql -u root -p" I got the message

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I discovered this was probably to do with Mariabd and so completely purged both mysql and Mariadb. Now when I try and re-install mysql I get the following message and after installation cannot log in to mysql

> Configuring mysql-server-5.7
>                                                                             Automatic maintenance of MySQL server daemon disabled
>   Packaging maintainer scripts detected a case that it does not know how
>   to handle and cannot continue configuring MySQL. Automatic management
>   of your MySQL installation has been disabled to allow other packaging
>   tasks to complete. For more details, see /etc/mysql/FROZEN.

The contents of etc/mysql/FROZEN read:

> his MySQL or variant installation has entered "frozen mode".
>   Maintainer scripts will avoid making changes or starting the daemon
>   until manually released from this state. See
>   /usr/share/doc/mysql-common/README for general information about this
>   mode.
>
> In this particular case, an incompatible downgrade attempt has been
>   detected. This can be resolved in one of two ways:
>
> 1. Change the contents of /var/lib/mysql/ to contain database data that is compatible with the currently installed MySQL or variant
>      daemon version. For example: you could restore from a backup.
>      Alternatively you could do a dump using a future version binary and
>      then a restore using the current version binary.
> 2. Switch to a MySQL or variant daemon version that is compatible with the data currently in /var/lib/mysql/. For example, if you have
>      attempted a downgrade from mysql-server-5.7 to mysql-server-5.6, you
>      could "apt install mysql-server-5.7" again.

I renamed the three files there that had to do with mysql and purged mysql again and tried another install, only to get the same message again.

Comment: Followed this solution and it works: https://askubuntu.com/a/873316/121418

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fixed it! The problem was the file /etc/mysql which wasn't being removed by purge. I renamed it with mv and then installed mysql-server and now I can log into mysql.

Comment: I faced MySQL has been frozen to prevent damage to your system. Please see /etc/mysql/FROZEN for help error.  In my case this works.  I simply removed /etc/mysql/ folder using `sudo rm -Rf /etc/mysql/
` command