# mysql server won't install on ubuntu 18.04 due to dpkg errors

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, mysql, dependencies

I want to install a mysql server. Eventually I want to run PHP scripts and I read that I need an sql server for that and mysql seems to be the recommended choice.

I tried to run`$ sudo apt install mysql-server` from the terminal. I remember that it did not  install mysql satisfactorily. When I ran `$ sudo systemctl status mysql` it told me that the server was `inactive (dead)`. I read some posts of people [reporting the same thing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068949/cannot-reinstall-mysql), and realised that `/etc/mysql` was not removed with the purge `$ sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server*`
. So I force-deleted it with root permisson. Maybe it wasn't a good idea, I don't know. Now I'm having trouble to even install the mysql server again.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-config-mailtransport kf5-kdepim-apps-libs-data kio-ldap kio-sieve
  libgrantlee-templates5 libgrantlee-textdocument5 libical2 libkf5akonadiagentbase5
  libkf5akonadicalendar-data libkf5akonadicalendar5abi2 libkf5akonadicontact-data
  libkf5akonadicontact5abi1 libkf5akonadicore-bin libkf5akonadicore5abi1
  libkf5akonadimime-data libkf5akonadimime5 libkf5akonadinotes-data
  libkf5akonadinotes5 libkf5akonadiprivate5 libkf5akonadisearchpim5
  libkf5akonadiwidgets5 libkf5alarmcalendar-data libkf5alarmcalendar5abi1
  libkf5calendarcore5abi1 libkf5calendarsupport-data libkf5calendarsupport5abi1
  libkf5calendarutils-bin libkf5calendarutils-data libkf5calendarutils5abi1
  libkf5contacteditor-data libkf5contacteditor5 libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5
  libkf5emoticons-bin libkf5emoticons-data libkf5emoticons5 libkf5eventviews-data
  libkf5eventviews5 libkf5identitymanagement-data libkf5identitymanagement5abi1
  libkf5imap-data libkf5imap5 libkf5incidenceeditor-bin libkf5incidenceeditor-data
  libkf5incidenceeditor5abi2 libkf5kdepimdbusinterfaces5 libkf5kontactinterface-data
  libkf5kontactinterface5 libkf5ldap-data libkf5ldap5 libkf5libkdepim-data
  libkf5libkdepim-plugins libkf5libkdepim5abi2 libkf5libkdepimakonadi5
  libkf5mailtransport-data libkf5mailtransport5abi2 libkf5mailtransportakonadi5
  libkf5mbox5 libkf5mime-data libkf5mime5abi2 libkf5pimcommon-plugins
  libkf5pimcommon5abi3 libkf5pimcommonakonadi5 libkf5pimtextedit-data
  libkf5pimtextedit5abi2 libkgantt2 libkgantt2-l10n libkolabxml1v5 libkpimgapi-data
  libkpimgapicalendar5 libkpimgapicontacts5 libkpimgapicore5 libkpimgapitasks5
  libkpimkdav-data libkpimkdav5 libkpimsmtp5 libllvm8 libllvm8:i386 libqt5webengine5
  linux-headers-4.15.0-64 linux-headers-4.15.0-64-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-64-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-64-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-64-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 191: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure- 
symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit 
status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a 
previous failure.
                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So it seems I got a dpkg error with `mysql-server-5.7` and one with `mysql-server`. Somehow things are not configured properly.

Then, when I run `sudo systemctl status mysql` I get:

```
$ sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

which leads me to believe, that again something went wrong in the installation.

When I type `sudo touch /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks; sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks; sudo dpkg --configure -a` - as [Kulfy](https://askubuntu.com/users/816190/kulfy) suggested - into the terminal I get the following output.

```
touch: cannot touch '/usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks': No 
such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks': No 
such file or directory
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 191: 
/usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script 
subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

Then trying to run `sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/mysql-common/` before the above command and then running that command yields:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
Please enable --log-error option or set appropriate redirections for 
standard output and/or standard error in daemon mode.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi- 
user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with 
error code. 
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 
2020-02-17 14:55:22 CET; 5ms ago
  Process: 11235 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre 
(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-5.7 package post-installation script 
subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

When I check `systemctl status mysql.service` I get the following output

```
$ systemctl status mysql.service
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enab
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-02-17 14:55:23 
CET; 20min ago
  Process: 11243 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre 
(code=exite

Feb 17 14:55:23 leonhard-ThinkPad-X240 systemd[1]: mysql.service: 
Service hold-off
Feb 17 14:55:23 leonhard-ThinkPad-X240 systemd[1]: mysql.service: 
Scheduled restar
Feb 17 14:55:23 leonhard-ThinkPad-X240 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL 
Community Server.
Feb 17 14:55:23 leonhard-ThinkPad-X240 systemd[1]: mysql.service: 
Start request re
Feb 17 14:55:23 leonhard-ThinkPad-X240 systemd[1]: mysql.service: 
Failed with resu
Feb 17 14:55:23 leonhard-ThinkPad-X240 systemd[1]: Failed to start 
MySQL Community
```

I started tackling the dpkg problems. Then I found on [this site](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-mysql-57-on-linux-centos-and-ubuntu/) a guide on installing MySQL 5.7. They suggested to to first add a repository from dev.mysql, so I sudo-ed `wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.3-1_all.deb` this statement into my terminal and then dpkg-ed it `dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.3-1_all.deb`. I got the following DOS like warning window in the terminal:

```
The detected system (ubuntu bionic) is not supported by MySQL. If you 
believe the platform is compatible with one of the supported systems, 
one of the corresponding repositories may be  │ 
 │ selected.                                                                                                                                                                                 
│ 
 │                                                                                                                                                                                           
│ 
 │ Add repository to unsupported system?
```

So maybe it has to do with the flavour of Ubuntu that I have?

Comment: If there is really a Problem with the apt database you could try to fix this by using "sudo apt install -f" else you can force reinstallation of mysql by adding "-f" to your apt command to force the installation even if the package is allready installed

Comment: What about the two erros with with 'mysql-server-5.7` and one with 'mysql-server` ?
When I type "sudo systemctl status mysql" I again get "mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)"

Comment: well - something got f***** up - perhaps something with the apt database - so let it try to repair itself at first. If this is not working it probably mentions what needs to be done.
"2 not fully installed or removed" - means you sould run the mentioned apt command

Comment: Thanks Kulfy, I'll edit the post to include the output of that command. Still seems to encounter problems with the mysql server

Comment: @Mr.Gosh `-f` doesn't install packages forcefully, instead it's a one character flag for `--fix-broken`. For more information, refer [`apt-get` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104570/discussion-between-kulfy-and-marlo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you somehow deleted Symlink configuration file. You can recreate that using:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/mysql-common/
sudo touch /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks
sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks
```

and paste

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

case "$1" in
  install)
    variant="$2"
    my_cnf_path="$3"
    update-alternatives --install /etc/mysql/my.cnf my.cnf "$my_cnf_path" 200
  ;;
  remove)
    variant="$2"
    my_cnf_path="$3"
    update-alternatives --remove my.cnf "$my_cnf_path"
  ;;
esac
```

It also seems that MySQL configuration folder was also deleted as indicated by the [output posted in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53563500#53563500). To fix that, run

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/mysql/conf.d/
echo "[mysql]" | sudo tee /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
sudo touch /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf
sudo chmod 644 /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf
```

and paste below contents in /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqldump.cnf.

```
[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
```

Now configure the unconfigured packages.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Check the status of MySQL using

```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

For more, please refer to the [transcript of the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/104570).